# Magento new theme with default data

Tags: magento

I have installed Magento CE 1.9.1.0 with sample data. I have copied the default theme of interface rwd and rename it as test theme. Update the package and theme from the admin panel and Save the same. But when refresh the front panel from browser no data will be displayed including images etc. Please help me to know what are the tricks behind the same.

- Why data is lost while new theme has been activated?
- How to see the sample data?
- What are the files am I need to configure more?

Answer (score 0):

you want to Customize RWD theme.in your rwd package you can make a new theme like

**design/frontend/rwd/yourtheme** and start copying the files which you want to customize in yourtheme.

copy files from **design/frontend/rwd/default** to **design/frontend/rwd/yourtheme** and start customization.

and also check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24730/correct-way-to-customize-rwd-theme-ce-1-9) too

Comment: I have done this already. My theme resides in app/design/frontend/test/tester1. So package is test and theme is tester. I have copied rwd theme to test package and rename it tester1. After activating the new theme tester1 I found it in frontend, but there is no data such as products etc. How to carry forward the data also in my new theme? One more issue - I bring another theme named tester2 within same package. Now I wish to activate the tester2, so that tester1 will hide. How do I make it? Is it possible to launch 3 website domains in 3 separate URLs via single magento installation and admin?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, you already create your own theme package and set it in the System > Configuration > Design (and correctly followed the magento fallback system) [Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy)

Next, if your working on locally, make sure to set the cache as disabled. Navigate to  System > Cache management and select all, refresh and then disabled it.

Comment: I have done this already. My theme resides in app/design/frontend/test/tester1. So package is test and theme is tester. I have copied rwd theme to test package and rename it tester1. After activating the new theme tester1 I found it in frontend, but there is no data such as products etc. How to carry forward the data also in my new theme? One more issue - I bring another theme named tester2 within same package. Now I wish to activate the tester2, so that tester1 will hide. How do I make it? Is it possible to launch 3 website domains in 3 separate URLs via single magento installation and admin?